# Opencv 4.0+ Displaying images as video stream crashes the system (How to add FPS while displaying images as Video stream)

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, python-imaging-library, object-detection

I am trying `KCF` with `Opencv 4.0` and using it on images. I have a directory where I have saved all the images of a videos. One idea is to first convert all the images in the directory with a desired `FPS` using: `cv2.VideoWriter()`

But I don't see a sense in that when I have already opened the images. My system crashes every time. I think because of the continuous images moving so rapidly. I need to add a FPS to the stream. Below is the code for the project. Please help.

```
files = sorted(glob.glob("data/*.jpg"))

tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()

initBB = None
fps = None

for i in files:
    frame = cv2.imread(i)
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
    (H, W) = frame.shape[:2]
    
    
    if initBB is not None:
        (success, box) = tracker.update(frame)
    
        if success:
            (x, y, w, h) = [int(v) for v in box]
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h),(0, 255, 0), 2)
       
        info = [
            ("Tracker", 'kcf'),
            ("Success", "Yes" if success else "No"),
        ]
      
        for (i, (k, v)) in enumerate(info):
            text = "{}: {}".format(k, v)
            cv2.putText(frame, text, (10, H - ((i * 20) + 20)),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, (0, 0, 255), 2)     
            
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord("s"):
        initBB = cv2.selectROI("Frame", frame, fromCenter=False,showCrosshair=True)
        tracker.init(frame, initBB)
        
    elif key == ord("q"):
        break
        
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What do you think `cv2.waitKey(1)` does?

Comment: Thanks! I just got to know it'll display for 1 milisecond But why is it crashing the kernel?

Comment: @alkasm Also, how do you keep the video freezed at frame until `ROI` is inserted. By the time I select, video is already gone.